How to escape "continuation hell"?
I'm currently writing a reactive web application with quarkus. Every so often, I find my self in something which I would call "continuation hell" where I chain several calls to the database until I have all the data I need for the response.
Take for example an endpoint that reads data from three Panache entities Foo, Bar and Baz and creates a MyDto instance with data from these entities. For this endpoint I would write code like this:
@GET
public Uni<MyDto> get(@QueryParam("criteria") String someCriteria) {
  return Foo.findBySomeCriteria(someCriteria)
          .chain(foo -> Bar.findBySomeCriteria(someCriteria)
            .chain(bar -> Baz.findBySomeCriteria(someCriteria)
              .map(baz -> new MyDto(
                foo.value,
                bar.value,
                baz.value
              ))
            )
          );
}

Although this is a trivial example, I allready have some significant indentation and boilerplate code intermixed with my (minimal) business logic. This makes the code hard to read. It only gets nastier as soon as I add error handling or special cases.
Unfortunately, I am not able to combine the Unis returned by Panache. This would give me an IllegalStateException with the message: "Illegal pop() with non-matching JdbcValuesSourceProcessingState" because it is not possible to start two operations on the reactive Hibernate session concurrently. Otherwise, a solution could look like this:
@GET
public Uni<MyDto> get(@QueryParam("criteria") String someCriteria) {
  // This does not work !!!
  Uni<Foo> fooUni = Foo.findBySomeCriteria(someCriteria);
  Uni<Bar> barUni = Bar.findBySomeCriteria(someCriteria);
  Uni<Baz> bazUni = Baz.findBySomeCriteria(someCriteria);
  
  return Uni.combine().all().unis(fooUni, barUni, bazUni)
    .with((foo, bar, baz) -> new MyDto(
      foo.value,
      bar.value,
      baz.value
    ));
}

So what are some good ways to escape this "continuation hell"?

While I'm not familiar with Quarkus, a common approach for what you're doing is to make all the calls essentially simultaneously, and to await them all completing. That works if the calls are independent of one another as in your example.

For more general info on this approach you might try googling Promise.all().

@ConnieMnemonic: This is exactly what I showed in the second example. Unfortunately, database calls with Hibernate can not be done simultaneously due to a bug/limitation in Hibernate Reactive: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-reactive/issues/1615#issuecomment-1532595457

Ah, my mistake, misread, apologies. Well, if that's the bug that's holding you up, and it says "chaining is the only reliable way", it sounds like you're stuck with chaining. Again, I know nothing about the technology you're using, I'm mostly Angular and .NET. But if I were looking at this, that would be my conclusion.

After examining the Mutiny Reference in more detail, I found that it is possible to limit the number of concurrent upstream subscriptions when combining Unis. By setting the concurrency to 1, the upstream Unis will execute sequentially, which avoids the Hibernate-related problems. Unfortunately, this approach means we loose type information about the elements, so we need to recreate it in the subscription.
The second example of combining the Unis would therefore work like this:
@GET
public Uni<MyDto> get(@QueryParam("criteria") String someCriteria) {
  Uni<Foo> fooUni = Foo.findBySomeCriteria(someCriteria);
  Uni<Bar> barUni = Bar.findBySomeCriteria(someCriteria);
  Uni<Baz> bazUni = Baz.findBySomeCriteria(someCriteria);
  
  return Uni.combine().all().unis(fooUni, barUni, bazUni)
    .usingConcurrencyOf(1)
    .with(results -> new MyDto(
      ((Foo) result.get(0)).value,
      ((Bar) result.get(1)).value,
      ((Baz) result.get(2)).value
    ));
}

Aside from the type problem, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Just because of curiosity: did you gain any performance benefits by going reactive with Hibernate ?

I haven't tested it yet; I'm still tinkering with it to get a better grasp of its ins and outs
